# Performance of a program that uses System.Reflection.Metadata varies for unknow reasons

Tags: c#, ntfs, system.reflection.metadata

The below program is a command line tool that takes a directory path as input, recursively scans it for files with `.dll` as extension and verifies whether those files are valid .NET assemblies. To do that verification, it uses the [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata/) NuGet package. Eventually, the name and version of all valid .NET assemblies is printed to the console.

The program works as intended but its performance strikes me as odd. Sometimes, if I let the program scan a directory with thousands of files it just takes dozens of seconds. During that time, there is a lot of disk load and both the first and the second time measurement of the program are unusually high. But running the program again with the same directory argument executes it very quickly, measured typically in a couple of 100 milliseconds.

I do not really understand that behavior. A possible explanation would be that the disk went sleeping but I have looked into this and it does not seem to explain the behavior. The program itself doesn't cache anything and terminates after the content has been printed to the console.

Is there a mechanism in Windows that explains why `var dllFilePaths = new DirectoryInfo(args[0]).GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` runs quicker when executed multiple times?

And why would the code that invokes readers from `System.Reflection.Metadata` run quicker when executed multiple times?

```cs
namespace AssemblyFinder
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Reflection.Metadata;
   using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

   public static class Program
   {
      public static int Main(string[] args)
      {
         if (args.Length != 1)
         {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Please specify the path of the directory to be scanned for .NET assemblies.");
            return 1;
         }

         if (!Directory.Exists(args[0]))
         {
            Console.Error.WriteLine($"The specified argument \"{args[0]}\" is not an existing directory.");
            return 2;
         }

         Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
         stopWatch.Start();

         var assemblies = new List<AssemblyInfo>();
         var dllFilePaths = new DirectoryInfo(args[0])
            .GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(dllFileInfo => dllFileInfo.FullName)
            .ToList();

         stopWatch.Stop();
         Console.WriteLine($"Found {dllFilePaths.Count} dlls in {(long)stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} milliseconds");
         stopWatch.Restart();

         foreach (var dllFilePath in dllFilePaths)
         {
            if (IsAssembly(dllFilePath, out var assemblyInfo))
            {
               assemblies.Add(assemblyInfo);
            }
         }

         stopWatch.Stop();

         foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
         {
            Console.WriteLine($"{assembly.FilePath} -> {assembly.AssemblyName}, {assembly.AssemblyVersion}");
         }

         Console.WriteLine($"Found {dllFilePaths.Count} dlls, identified {assemblies.Count} assemblies in {(long)stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} milliseconds");
         return 0;
      }

      private static bool IsAssembly(string filePath, out AssemblyInfo assemblyInfo)
      {
         using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
         using (var peReader = new PEReader(fileStream))
         {
            if (!peReader.PEHeaders.IsDll || !peReader.HasMetadata)
            {
               assemblyInfo = null;
               return false;
            }

            var metadataReader = peReader.GetMetadataReader();
            if (!metadataReader.IsAssembly)
            {
               assemblyInfo = null;
               return false;
            }

            var assemblyDefinition = metadataReader.GetAssemblyDefinition();
            assemblyInfo = new AssemblyInfo()
            {
               AssemblyName = assemblyDefinition.Name.IsNil ? null : metadataReader.GetString(assemblyDefinition.Name),
               AssemblyVersion = assemblyDefinition.Version,
               FilePath = filePath,
            };

            return true;
         }
      }
   }

   public class AssemblyInfo
   {
      public string AssemblyName
      {
         get;
         set;
      }

      public Version AssemblyVersion
      {
         get;
         set;
      }

      public string FilePath
      {
         get;
         set;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Running the program again on data already read earlier means all the I/O gets serviced from the operating system cache. Your program doesn't need to do anything special for this, and indeed effort has to be expended to tell the OS to *not* cache the data.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think I don't understand what you mean by "... and indeed effort has to be expended to tell the OS to not cache the data". Which entity would be telling the OS not to cache data?

Comment: You can explicitly tell Windows that data should not be cached by passing `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` to `CreateFile`. This is not explicitly surfaced in .NET -- the `FileOptions` enum doesn't expose a separate value for it -- but oddly enough, there is explicit code to allow passthrough of this flag value anyway if you force the issue (`(FileOptions) 0x20000000`).